# Using two button in a form calling different actions

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, forms

I have a form on my page:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("DoReservation","Reservation"))
{
...some inputs
<button id="recalculate">Recalculate price</button>
<button id="submit">Submit</button>
}
```

When I click the "Recalculate price" button I want the following action to be invoked:

```
public ActionResult Recalculate(FormCollection form)
{
 var price = RecalculatePrice(form);
 ... do some price recalculation based on the inputs
return PartialView("PriceRecalculation",price);
}
```

When I click the "Submit" button I want the "DoReservation" action to be invoked (I want the form to be submitted).
How can I achieve something like that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you handle multiple submit buttons in ASP.NET MVC Framework?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/442704/how-do-you-handle-multiple-submit-buttons-in-asp-net-mvc-framework)

Comment: @JasCav may be correct about it being a duplicate.. another option may be to use jquery to attach to the button click to rewrite the form action before it is submitted?

Comment: @TrevorPilley - You are correct, you could do that. But, then you are relying on JavaScript (which is typically fair, but not always guaranteed). The method(s) I linked to in the duplicate will work in all cases.

Comment: I want the first action to return a partial view with a price specification and place it in some div on my page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I can suggest is , adding a new property to your view model and call it ActionType.

```
public string ActionType { get; set; }
```

and then change your cshtml file like below

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        <div id="mytargetid">    
                ...some inputs*@
        </div>
        <button type="submit" name="actionType" value="Recalculate" >Recalculate price</button>
        <button type="submit" name="actionType" value="DoReservation" >Submit</button>
 }
```

in post action method based on ActionType value you can decide what to do !

I noticed that in your comments you mentioned you need to return partial and replace if with returning partial , no problem , you can use

```
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("DoProcess", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "mytargetid", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }))
```

and in controller change your action to return partial view or java script code to redirect page

```
 public ActionResult DoProcess(FormModel model)
        {
            if (model.ActionType == "Recalculate")
            {
                return PartialView("Test");
                }
            else if (model.ActionType == "DoReservation")
            {
                return JavaScript(string.Format("document.location.href='{0}';",Url.Action("OtherAction")));


            }
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: @Azadah Khojandi thank you for your answer - but I mentioned that only the "recalculation" action should return the partial view and replace the content of a specific div. The second action should redirect to some view. Well, generally it can also works in a way where partial views are returned from both actions, but they will have to replace the different divs.

Comment: @niao for redirect to different page in ajax call you can use return JavaScript(string.Format("document.location.href='{0}';",Url.Action("About")));